# Is $f_n(z) = \dfrac {2nz - 1} {z + n^2}$ uniformly convergent on the disc $|z| <1$?

Tags: complex-analysis

The pointwise limit of $f_n(z) = \dfrac {2nz - 1} {z + n^2}$ is $0$.

By the triangle inequality,

$\Bigg|\dfrac {2nz - 1} {z + n^2}\Bigg| \le \Bigg|\dfrac {2nz} {z + n^2}\Bigg| + \Bigg|\dfrac {1} {z + n^2}\Bigg|$

On the disc $|z| <1$, $\Bigg|\dfrac {1} {z + n^2}\Bigg|\le \dfrac {1} {n^2} \le \dfrac {1} {n}$. However I cannot seem to find bounds for $\Bigg|\dfrac {2nz} {z + n^2}\Bigg|$.

I'm beginning to think that the sequence is only pointwise convergent in the specified disc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, $|1/(z+n^2)| \le 1/n^2$ fails. Try $z=-1/2$ for example. Instead note that for $n>1,$

$$\left |\frac{2nz-1}{z+n^2}\right | \le \frac{|2nz|+1}{n^2 - |z|} \le \frac{2n+1}{n^2 - 1}.$$

Comment: Thanks, @zhw. So now, $\Bigg| \dfrac {1} {n^2 -1} \Bigg| \le \Bigg| \dfrac {1} {n^2}\Bigg| \le \Bigg| \dfrac {1} {n} \Bigg|$. But what about $\Bigg| \dfrac {2n} {n^2 - 1} \Bigg|$?

Comment: No, you're making the same mistake. That first inequality is wrong. As for $(2n+1)/(n^2-1),$ just show it goes to $0.$

Comment: Thanks for the catch, @zhw.